# will paginate, nested routes, ruby, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

I'm trying to get will paginate to link to my nested route instead of the regular posts variable. I know I'm supposed to pass some params to paginate but I don't know how to pass them.

Basically there is an array stored in `@posts` and the other param paginate has access to is `category_id`.

The nested route is `/category/1/posts` but hitting next and previous on will paginate returns a url like this `posts?page=1&category_id=7`.

```
 <%= will_paginate @most_recent_posts "What do I do here?" %>
```

---

This is the result of Yannis's answer:

In your controller you can do:

```
@posts = @category.posts.paginate
```

And in your view:

```
<%= will_paginate(@post) %>
```

Doing this comes up with the following URL

```
posts?page=2&post_category_id=athlete_management
```

---

routes.rb #there are more routes but these are the relevant ones

```
map.resources :posts
map.resources :post_categories, :has_many => :posts
```

## solution

```
 map.resources :post_categories do |post_category|
   post_category.resources :posts
  end
  map.resources :posts
```

Had to declare the resource after the block

Thanks stephen!

Comment: Show your nested routes from `routes.rb`. Yannis's answer is absolutely correct and it works out of the box for me.

Comment: so you can paginate your category/1/posts/page=2, and so on like that.

Comment: If you actually are using nested routes with a url like `/category/1/posts` Doesn't that imply that your routes should look something like: `map.resources :category do |cat| cat.resources :posts end` That's the proper way to do nested resources. If you've only defined an action called "posts" in the category controller, that's not actually nested routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parachuting in here on this old question because I encountered the same issue.

I had pretty much exactly the same problem. I followed the responders' advice that something funky was going on with the routes. I dug into the routes and found (translated to suit your situation):

```
resources :posts
resources :categories do
  resources :posts
end
```

This made it so that calling `category_posts_path` returned (as expected) `/category/1/posts`.

However, it's of pivotal importance to realize that `will_paginate` calls something that resembles `url_for`, which works "backwards" from the routes to find the first route that matches the parameters.

Since `resources :posts` appears above the nested route, it sees that that one satisfies the requirements and just inserts `category_id=1` was a query string.

The reason it worked "out of the box" for everyone else was because they didn't have the nested resource separately listed as a standalone resource.

Remove that and you should be fine!

Comment: Thanks, I still had to declare the resource by doing it after the block in routes.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you can do:

```
@posts = @category.posts.paginate
```

And in your view:

```
<%= will_paginate(@post) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so it's not clear from the question exactly, but I'm assuming that you are trying to go from a root-level URL like `/posts` into pages for specific categories like `/category/1/posts`.

The reason I assume this is because I have nested routes (in a namespace even) where will_paginate works fine without any special params.  If that is not the case then there is probably something else funky going on with your routes and more information will be needed to debug.

However I can at least explain how will_paginate works.  When it's generating the page URLs it calls `url_for` with existing params plus the specific page needed.  Therefore, if you already have a bunch of params set, it should preserve them, including ones that are part of the path itself.  Fortunately it also allows you to pass additional params to merge in with the (surprise!) `:params` parameter to will_paginate.

Now assuming you have the nested routes set up properly, `/category/1/posts` can be generated by:

```
url_for(:controller => 'posts', 
        :category_id => '1')
```

But if you are on the page `/posts` then the params will only be:

```
{:controller => 'posts'}
```

So you need to pass the category_id to will_paginate like so:

```
<%= will_paginate @posts, :params => {:category_id => @posts.first.category_id} %>
```

If this doesn't work, then I suspect something wrong with your routes.  Try putting a debug statement in the template and calling `url_for` with different permutations of the params.  Remember that the route definition order matters and could be creating conflicts.

Comment: `/category/1/posts/page=2` that is the way I want the url to look when I paginate through the posts in the category.

Comment: Did you read what I said?  Did you try it?  You didn't respond to my questions or indicate anything.  No one is going to give you more than I have.  If it doesn't work and you need more help then you're going to have to post more information.

Comment: you didn't explicitly say that you have pagination working with nested routes. such that it creates the url I'm trying to achieve. Have you actually paginated the category/1/posts/ url and still get that url but with the page appended to the end?

Comment: Yes I did explicitly state it, that's what I meant by "The reason I assume this is because I have nested routes (in a namespace even) where will_paginate works fine without any special params."

Comment: I was referring to the fact that you used a slash instead of a question mark before page.  The information I've given you is the best you're going to get.  From here on out you need to debug it yourself or else post more detailed information.